# C casting syntax and typedef

Tags: c, casting, typedef

C declaration syntax is fairly convoluted ...

Which brings me to my question regarding casting syntax,

Simple types are easy enough, just put the type in brackets.
But what about types like,

`int (*2Dap) [5];` or `double (*fp) (double, double);`

I guessing here, the rule is to just strip away the identifier (plus the semicolon) of a normal variable declaration and put it in brackets.

So, `int (*2Dap) [5];` becomes `( int (*) [5] )` and `char * str;` becomes just `(char *)`

Is this a general rule?

As so `typedef`, your new "type" would be what is your "variable" in your `typedef` declaration,

eg. `typedef double (*twoINoneOUT) (double, double);` "twoInoneOUT" would be your new "type".

Correct??

Just wanted to clarify. I know I'm unlikely to even need to cast these - could save me from having to typedef unnecessarily though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guessing here, the rule is to just strip away the identifier (plus
>   the semicolon) of a normal variable declaration and put it in
>   brackets.

Right.  This declares a variable called `x`:

```
int (*x)[5];
```

The type of the variable is `int (*)[5]`, and you could cast to that type using the cast `(int (*)[5])`.

> As so typedef, your new "type" would be what is your "variable" in
>   your typedef declaration,

Also correct.  This declares a type alias called `t`:

```
typedef int (*t)[5];
```

Syntactically, `typedef` appears in the same place as a storage class specifier like `static`.

Comment: It's not `typedef int (*)[5] t;`?

Comment: @JAB: No - as stated, `typedef` works like a storage class specifier; it has the same syntax as an object declaration.

Comment: Hm, I never knew that. Guess it's due to me mainly using `typedef` with structs rather than arrays and such.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

and this can be useful for what looks like total gibberish

http://cdecl.org/

Comment: I more or less got the declaration thing, as long as it doesn't get too complicated. Was wondering more about casting and typedef usage. Still thanks for the sites, could come in handy.

Comment: If you cast a lot, then typedef first and cast to the typedef. Everyone will love you.

Comment: @Kerrek SB  Just curious how to do it without typedefs, if I ever need to do a lot of casting I would probably use typedefs to keep my sanity and leave the "brute force" method for when it's a "waste" to do a typedef declaration.

Comment: Well, if it's just to typecast maybe once or twice, declaring a typedef feels like overkill, but I have not written any large programs yet with high levels of complexity - none of what I have done really required using typedef.  I will keep your advise in mind when the time comes. PS: Also as I mentioned, I kind of just wanted to know how to do it.